# Dynamically allocated 2d array of strings from file

Tags: c, string, dynamic-arrays

This question might be common but I did not find anything close to this exact problem so I will ask. I have a file that looks like this.

```
ABCSTRX
ABCST
ABCS
ABCSTRXY
```

My task is to create 2D array of strings. For each string it allocates only needed space (length of string), so it will look like this.

[image: the red area is for '\0']

> 

So far in my code I have scanned through file and got number representing the amount of strings in file.

```
void function(FILE *txt){
    char arr[50];
    int counter=0;
    char **array;

    do {                                    
       fgets(arr,MAX,txt);
       counter++;
    } while(fgets(arr,MAX,txt)!=NULL);

    rewind(txt);
    array = malloc(counter * sizeof(char*));


    //FROM NOW ON THE CODE IS NOT CORRECT
    do {                                    
        fgets(arr,MAX,txt);
        counter++;

        for(int j=0;j<strlen(arr); j++){
            array[i]= malloc(strlen(arr) * sizeof(char));
            array[i]= arr;
        }
        i++;
    } while(fgets(arr,MAX,txt)!=NULL);

}
```

Problem is that I cant find a solution how to fill my dynamically allocated array with strings which size does not match. This is the code that I have come up with and I feel stuck. After the array is filled with strings it will be printed(with two for cycles I suppose). Thanks for comments

Comment: My crystal ball tells me this question has been asked and answerd many times on SO.

Comment: `for(int j=0;j<strlen(arr); j++){
            array[i]= malloc(strlen(arr) * sizeof(char));
            array[i]= arr;
        }` --> `array[i]= malloc((strlen(arr)+1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(array[i], arr);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider the following commented compilable C code.
Instead of writing some notes here, I've inserted several comments inline in the code, to try to clearly explain what the code is doing.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* For printf and file management */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* For dynamic memory allocation */
#include <string.h>     /* For string functions */

/* 
 * Read all lines from text file, and store them in a dynamically 
 * allocated array. 
 * The count of lines is stored in the 'count' output parameter
 * The caller is responsible for freeing the allocated memory.
 */
char** read_lines(FILE* txt, int* count) {
    char** array = NULL;        /* Array of lines */
    int    i;                   /* Loop counter */
    char   line[100];           /* Buffer to read each line */
    int    line_count;          /* Total number of lines */
    int    line_length;         /* Length of a single line */

    /* Clear output parameter. */
    *count = 0;

    /* Get the count of lines in the file */
    line_count = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), txt) != NULL) {                                      
       line_count++;
    }

    /* Move to the beginning of file. */
    rewind(txt);

    /* Allocate an array of pointers to strings 
     * (one item per line). */
    array = malloc(line_count * sizeof(char *));
    if (array == NULL) {
        return NULL; /* Error */
    }

    /* Read each line from file and deep-copy in the array. */
    for (i = 0; i < line_count; i++) {    
        /* Read the current line. */
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), txt);

        /* Remove the ending '\n' from the read line. */
        line_length = strlen(line);        
        line[line_length - 1] = '\0';
        line_length--; /* update line length */

        /* Allocate space to store a copy of the line. +1 for NUL terminator */
        array[i] = malloc(line_length + 1);

        /* Copy the line into the newly allocated space. */
        strcpy(array[i], line);
    }

    /* Write output param */
    *count = line_count;

    /* Return the array of lines */
    return array;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char**      array    = NULL;    /* Array of read lines */
    FILE*       file     = NULL;    /* File to read lines from */
    const char* filename = NULL;    /* Name of the input file */
    int         i;                  /* Loop index */
    int         line_count;         /* Total number of read lines *7

    /* Get filename from the command line. */
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Specify the input file from the command line.\n");
        return 1;
    }    
    filename = argv[1];

    /* Try opening the file. */
    file = fopen(filename, "rt");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file %s.\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Read lines from file. */
    array = read_lines(file, &line_count);

    /* Just for test, print out the read lines. */
    for (i = 0; i < line_count; i++) {
        printf("[%d]: %s\n", (i+1), array[i]);
    }

    /* Cleanup. */
    fclose(file);
    for (i = 0; i < line_count; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
    array = NULL;

    /* All right */
    return 0;
}
```

With an input file like this:

> ```
> ABCSTRX
> ABCST
> ABCS
> ABCSTRXY
> ```

The output is:

> ```
> C:\Temp>test.exe testfile.txt
> [1]: ABCSTRX
> [2]: ABCST
> [3]: ABCS
> [4]: ABCSTRX
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your `do while` loop to count the number of lines in the file won't work because you are calling `fgets` twice in each iteration- once in the body of the loop and the next time to check the condition - while updating counter only once.

Also, `strlen` does not count the terminating null byte but you have to allocate space for it. Here is my update to your function.

```
void function(FILE *txt) {
    char arr[50];
    int counter = 0;
    char **array;

    while(fgets(arr, sizeof arr, txt)!=NULL)                                          
       counter++;

    rewind(txt);
    array = malloc(counter * sizeof *array);

    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        fgets(arr, sizeof arr, txt);
        array[i] = malloc(strlen(a) + 1); // +1 for the terminating null byte
        strcpy(array[i], arr);  // copy the string to the buffer
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you missed the closing `}` in the `while` loop to get the line count in the `counter` variable (or you may want to remove the open brace `{`...).